# Front-end SQL Search - Dynamically check similar values?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a front-end DB search on my website: https://ygoprodeck.com

Currently it checks card names. A user can type in "**magician**" and get loads of results.
But if a user mis-spells it and types "**magican**" then no results show.

I've been tracking user inputs and it seems a lot of users are mis-spelling card names and getting no results.

A common example: There are cards with **D/D/D** in the name but users often type **DDD** which means they get no results.

Is there a **pure SQL** method to modify this behaviour or would it need to be implemented through JS/PHP?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about saving all the mis-spells in new table like

```
CREATE TABLE misSpells(
misSpell VARCAHR, 
correspondingOne VARCHAR
) 
Examples:
    magician, magician
    magican, magician
    DDD, DDD
    D/D/D, DDD
```

and query this table for the corresponding one?